# could not send a mail using SMTP server and AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, smtp, outlook-2007

I'm new to asp.net MVC. I'm trying to send a mail with attachment using SMTP server and AJAX in asp.net MVC. The mail could not be sent.

HomeController.cs

```
public JsonResult SendMailToUser()
    {
        bool result = false;
        result = SendEmail("Receiver_mail", "Test", "<p>Hi abc,<br/>This message is for testing purpose. So don't be upset.<br/>Kind Regards,<br/>abc</p>");
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public bool SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody)
    {
        try
        {
            string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sender_Mail.com"].ToString();
            string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Outlook@123"].ToString();

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody);
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;

            client.Send(mailMessage);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Layout.cshtml

```
<button type="submit" id ="export" onclick="SendEmail()" class="Layoutbuttons" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>get report via mail</span></button>

<script>
var SendEmail = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Home/SendMailToUser",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

Web.config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="SenderEmail" value="Sender_Mail" />
<add key="SenderPassword" value="Outlook@123" />
</appSettings>
```

Is there anything that need to be done in Outlook 2007 settings? The outlook 2007 runs on Exchange server.

Comment: What is your question? Do you catch any exception? Which one? At which line of code? Do you investigate Exchange log files? Is there any errors/warnings? Do they have any codes or something, that we can google?

Comment: I have received an alert message as "Success" in the web page after clicking the button but the mail was not received at the recipient's end.

Comment: `alert("Success");` will be shown if server respond with status code 200. Your controller action `SendMailToUser` _always_ return status code 200 as I can see. Again: What is your question? Do you catch any exception? Which one? At which line of code? Do you investigate Exchange log files? Is there any errors/warnings? Do they have any codes or something, that we can google?

Comment: @Nelson Kingsley, did u try to send mail to any other email address rather than outlook?

Comment: just need to check is your sending mail code works fine or not

Comment: @NelsonKingsley, your code look similar to this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/700211/Csharp-SMTP-Configuration-for-Outlook-Com-SMTP-Hos except for you have disabled SSL. Have you tried `client.EnableSsl = true;` ?

Comment: You have two completely different concerns, and you're mixing them up in your question which is making things far more complicated than they should be. Whether an email is successful or not has nothing to do with AJAX. You need to narrow down which side is actually having an issue. You should separate your email logic into its own class, and have that class implement an interface. Then your controller should not refer to the class directly, except perhaps in the constructor if you're not using Dependency Injection. You should code your action method against the interface.

Comment: By doing that, you'll be able to ensure your controller logic and AJAX logic properly handles email sending failures, without wondering whether the email logic is functioning or not.

Comment: And if you're going to catch an exception, don't just return false. Actually log the exception so you know *why* it failed to send. There's a number of great logging libraries out there, such as [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) and [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).

Comment: SendEmail probably shouldn't return a boolean. You're trying to indicate that an email was sent successfully or not, right? Well that should be a rare occurrence, so you should probably let the exception bubble up to some place where you want to take different action. The method itself should return void. Also, that very long timeout is going to be bad for your app: it's going to take up a thread for a tremendous amount of time if there are connection issues. Better to have a more reasonable timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions! I found the following solution. It works in localhost perfectly but fails after publishing! Kindly suggest a way out!

HomeController.cs

```
    public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application GetActiveOutlookApplication()
    {
        return (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
    }

    public void SendMailToUser()
    {
        try
        {
            Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mail = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
            mail.Subject = "Test mail";
            mail.Body = "Test";

            Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser = app.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
            if (currentUser.Type == "EX")
            {
                Outlook.ExchangeUser user = currentUser.GetExchangeUser();
                // Add recipient using display name, alias, or smtp address
                mail.Recipients.Add(user.PrimarySmtpAddress);
                mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
                mail.Attachments.Add(@"URL", Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                mail.Send();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Layout.cshtml

```
<button type="submit" id ="export" onclick="SendEmail()" class="Layoutbuttons" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Get report via mail</span></button>



<script>
var SendEmail = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '@Url.Action("SendMailToUser", "Home")',
        success: function () {
            alert("Mail sent successfully!");
        }
    })
}
</script>
```